# Change of research field

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-process, masters, research-undergraduate, changing-fields

I am an undergrad physics student and my research experience has mainly been in the field of Condensed Matter Physics. Through the experience I have come to realize that it is not what I want to continue with and wish to change my specialization when I apply for my masters. If I were to contact an advisor from a field different from the one I have some experience working in to join a group for say a Research Masters, will the experience (despite it being in a different field) work in my favour?

Comment: I am very confused by the close flag. This is an undergraduate student with research experience wanting to change specialization when apply for masters. Why close it by "Problems facing undergraduate students"? If this is a mistake, please retract it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any closed flags...

Comment: You won't because your reputation is not >3k yet.

Comment: It really depends 'how different'... without this information it is not possible to give an answer.  Even then, it would likely be far too subject specific to give a meaningful answer here.  I'd recommend discussing this with an academic that you trust for advice.

Comment: There are lot's of people changing their field after finishing a PhD. Or even faculty changing it in relation to new topics coming up and new research interests. I don't think this is a too big risk for an undergrad. Go for it!

Comment: My undergraduate degree was in Electrical Engineering. My masters/PhD was in Materials Science. My career has been in (not enough characters to list all the fields and subfields). Switching between bachelors and masters is quite, quite common (physics to chemistry, EE to bioengineering, ...).

Answer (score 0):

> Will the experience (despite it being in a different field) work in my favour?

Yes.  You will be showing that you are careful and meticulous in lab work, that you follow instructions and follow safety procedures, that you figure things out, that you correctly apply what you have been taught, that you are creative, that you have initiative, that you understand the scientific method, that you document your work, that you know how to take careful measurements and analyze your data, etc. etc.